# ansible- host alias with dynamic inventory

Tags: ansible

I have the following static inventory file:

```
[nodes:children]
masters
workers

[masters]
node1 ansible_host=1.2.3.4 ansible_port=2220 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_private_key_file=keys/id_rsa

[workers]
node2 ansible_host=1.2.3.4 ansible_port=2221 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_private_key_file=keys/id_rsa
```

Because my hosts use the same IP, but different ssh ports I need to alias them to so that ansible can see them as two hosts.

I'm trying to use a dynamic inventory script to generate this, but I'm struggling to find any information on the format of the json the I need to return, more specifically - how to alias the hosts.

So my question - does anyone know the json equivalent of the above static inventory file or somewhere where I can find information on the json format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read [this doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html) about writing dynamic inventory scripts.

There are two steps:

1) `script --list` should return groups with variables and hosts names in that groups (in your example, you should return groups: `nodes`, `masters`, `workers` and hosts: `node1` and `node2`).

2) `script --host <hostname>` should return hosts' variables (in your example connection variables like `ansible_host` and `ansible_port`).

So, in your example, inventory script should return 3 different json objects when executed with `--list`, `--host node1` and `--host node2`.

Comment: ahh, yes, I did read that, but I didn't realize ansible will make several calls to the script. Thanks for pointing that out